# Why can’t I use a thread handle which is stored in a struct?

Tags: rust

I want to implement an executor. I want to store the thread handle in a struct, so I can join it later, waiting for the threads to stop gracefully.

But I get an error when I try to call the `join()` method. I would like to know the reason and how to fix that.

```rust
struct Executor{
    tx:Sender<Box<dyn Send + Fn()>>,
    t:JoinHandle<()>,
}
impl Executor {
    fn new()->Self{
        let (tx, rx) = mpsc::channel::<Box<dyn Send + Fn()>>();
        let handle = thread::spawn(move || {
            loop{
                //TODO: check stop flag
                rx.recv().unwrap()();
            }
        });
       
        let ins = Executor{tx:tx, t:handle};
        ins
    }
    fn sender(&self)->Sender<Box<dyn Send + Fn()>>{
        self.tx.clone()
    }
    fn join(&self){
        self.t.join().unwrap();
    }
}
```

The error:

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of `self.t` which is behind a shared reference
  --> src\main.rs:77:9
   |
77 |         self.t.join().unwrap();
   |         ^^^^^^ move occurs because `self.t` has type `JoinHandle<()>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot use it like that, because the [`join()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/thread/struct.JoinHandle.html#method.join) method takes ownership of the handle, thus moving it out of the struct.

```rust
pub fn join(self) -> Result<T>
```

But if you take it out of the struct, then that memory location would contain invalid data and your struct would be in invalid state. Imagine you call `join()` once, the handle is moved out of the struct, then you try to call `join()` for a second time - the second call would access uninitialized memory, which is UB.

So you have to handle the case when there is no `JoinHandle` present. This can be done by using `Option<JoinHandle>`:

```rust
struct Executor{
    tx:Sender<Box<dyn Send + Fn()>>,
    t: Option<JoinHandle<()>>,
}
```

Then your join method can safely take out the handle from the struct:

```rust
fn join(&mut self){
    if let Some(handle) = self.t.take(){
        handle.join().unwrap();
    }
}
```

As @user4815162342 has noted in the comments, in that particular case it might be better to make your `join()` accept `self`instead of using `Option<JoinHandle<>>`in order to prevent someone from using the executor after it has been stopped:

```rust
fn join(self){
    self.t.join().unwrap();
}
```

Comment: I really knew the reason, thank you very much!

Comment: @Keanyuan Another option is to have the `join()` method on your `Executor` also accept `self` by value, which causes `self.t.join().unwrap()` [to compile](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=2da9205c57f87f84ded84515ccc19068). It has the additional benefit of allowing (at compile time) `Executor::join()` to only be called once and making the `Executor` object unusable after it (which makes sense, since it has just shut down its worker).